# I transferred my tokens to an ATA derived from an ATA. Can I get them back?

Tags: spl-token, ata

I transferred token to an associated token account derived from an associated token account, can I get my tokens back?

Answer (score 2):

Not right now. But very soon yes, possibly even this week!

The associated token account program is getting updated with a "recover nested account ix" feature to allow such recovery.

Details in this pull request
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/2889

trent.sol loves it

Comment: actually this ix belong to associated token program,right?

Comment: oups, yes of course, i edited the answer

Comment: lol :trollface:

Answer (score 1):

Once ownership of the account has been transferred to the token program all that matters is who is the "owner" of the token account. The owner can sign for transferring tokens. It depends if you have access to the private key or PDA program of the owner.